# Parse auto login -- hide login screen

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently using Parse to handle accounts in my app. Using the PFUser.currentUser feature, I have implemented automatic login for users who have logged in to the app once on their device. The issue is, when the app is opened, for about a second the login screen is displayed while Parse authenticates the current user. Would it be possible to display a loading icon, or just any other screen? It may be confusing, and it certainly is not ideal UI, for the login screen to show for a second every time the user opens the app. Any ideas/fixes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What i tend to do in this situation is to create a ViewController that looks exactly the same as your splash screen. This screen then decides which route the user should be directed in, e.g. if they are already logged in, allow them straight into the app, if not then take them to the login view.

Answer (score 1):

are you sing viewWillAppear? because i am using parse too and am not getting this issue? the code i use if

```
override func viewWillAppear() {

if PFUser.currentUser == nil {
//run your code to login the user, eg show login view controller 
}
```

if you put this code on your entry storyboard view controller then it will only show the login/signup view controller if it needs to, instead of dismissing it if user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the initial view controller of your app is the login view controller so it will always show it before it pushes another vc. One solution will be to separate your login view controller (no segue connection with any of the controllers) and make the navigation vc (or the first vc) your entry point and initiate the login vc from app delegate only if its user's first login. Here is an example on how to do that

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        if //first login {
            //Assuming you used navigation controller
            let navController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            let loginController = LoginViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard(navController.storyboard!)

            navController.presentViewController(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } 

    return true
}
```